# Identify LCD display orientation

Tags: lcd, character-lcd

When buying an HD44780 compatible LCD display with a backlight, is there a way to identify the orientation of the text on the LCD based on a standard part number?

I'm asking because I don't want to order new LCD's with backlights and then realize that the LCD has to be switched the other way and my circuit looking funny only to get the LCD to work.

Comment: That's what datasheets are for.

Comment: But isn't there a basic identification to go by without requiring a datasheet? I mean people don't have to look at hundreds of datasheets to find logic gates because they are standardized by number. for example, the AND gate ends in 08 if the number starts with 74.

Comment: If you have the "standard" part number, find the data sheet for that. IS the LCD in question a character type display or a dot matric graphic type? Please give a few specifics to keep the question confined.